# codeigniter store object in session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

When I am trying to save object in session using codeigniter

```
<pre>
$this->session->set_userdata($user_info);
the following error is shown

Severity: Warning
Message: Illegal offset type
Filename: Session/Session.php

Where $user_info = stdClass Object(
    [users_id] => 1
    [users_firstname] => Ahmar
    [users_lastname] => Arshad
    [users_email] => ahmar.arshad@swenggco-software.com
    [user_image] => 
    [users_role] => 1
    [users_deleted] => 0
);
</pre>
```

But when I convert that object into array and then store in session it works fine. Can anybody help me out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening because you are setting your session incorrectly.

You need to edit it in this format:

```
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_info', $user_info);
```